# how do i pass datastring parameter for jquery's .ajax() function properly?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var username = $('#username').val();

var dataString = 'username=' + username;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "signinout.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('.user').html('<span>Welcome <span id="loggedUser">' + username + '</span>!</span> <a id="signOut" onclick="window.location.reload()">SIGN OUT</a>');
        }
    });
```

using the above code, my username variable is not being passed on correctly, I'm assuming something is wrong with the way I coding the datastring parameter but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Below is the php code that I am using in signinout.php to insert the username into the database, the username field is not being entered with each new entry into the database.

```
$username = protect($_POST['username']);
$time = time();

$sql = "INSERT INTO users
    (username, join_date)
        VALUES
    ('$username', '$time')";
$result = mysqli_query($cn, $sql) or
    die(mysqli_error($cn));
```

Comment: var dataString = 'username=' + username;  replace this line with var dataString = {'username': username};

Comment: data: dataString, replace by data : {'username': username},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "best" datastring depends on your needs in the server side part. As an example, this jquery-ajax call send a object to a server side action (PHP) :

```
var mydata = null;

mydata = "hellostring=1";
mydata = { title: "some" , value: "thing" };
mydata = [1,2,3];

$.ajax({
   cache: false, type: 'post', async: true, 
   data: mydata,
   url: 'some-script.php',
   success: function(resp){
       console.log("OK",resp);
   },
   error: function(e){
       console.log(e.responseText);
   }
});
```

As result, in your serve side you may have this script, which will return the same as you send:

```
// some-script.php
<?php 
    echo print_r($_POST,true);
?>
```

The outputs, for each kind of data (see the mydata variable) is:

**Case**: mydata = "hellostring=1";

```
    Array( [hellostring] => "1" )
```

this mean, in serverside, you can:

```
 $_123 = $_POST["hellostring"];
```

**Case** mydata = { title: "some" , value: "thing" };

As result, you get:

```
Array
(
    [title] => some
    [value] => thing
)
```

So you can:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];  $value = $_POST['value'];
```

**Case** mydata = [1,2,3];

Surprise, this doesnt work, :) , you should wrap it, in this form:

mydata = { some : [1,2,3] }

So, you can proceed in your server-side the same as the previous case.

**Note:**

To avoid get hacked: (PHP CASE example) filter your input using:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php

**More**

In order to have a more advanced data handling in your server side part, (that is: in the script who receive the ajax request) ,  you can make usage of json, in this way:

Let start by supposing you are sending a object via javascript:

```
// in your client part, 
   mydata = { title: "some" , value: "thing", mydog: "sammy" };
   ..do your ajax call stuff here..
```

And, in your server side:

```
   <?php
       // some-script.php
       $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
       echo $obj->title;  // output: "some"
       echo $obj->value;  // output: "thing"
       echo $obj->mydog;  // output: "sammy"
   ?>
```

Comment: you deserve an upvote for such a detailed answer. you are too kind

Answer (score 0):

try passing it as a regular javascript object

```
var dataObj = {'username': username};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "signinout.php",
    data: dataObj,
```

Comment: that code doesn't seem to make it work either, is it possible that another part of my code is wrong?

Comment: perhaps look at your network panel and see what the request looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data: "username="+username,` instead

```
var username = $('#username').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "signinout.php",
    data: "username=" + username,
    success: function() {
        $('.user').html('<span>Welcome <span id="loggedUser">' + username + '</span>!</span> <a id="signOut" onclick="window.location.reload()">SIGN OUT</a>');
    }
});
```